# vue js 2 - for loop in multiple rest calls fetchData

Tags: rest, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to get wp-rest and Vuejs 2 to work together, so far things are coming along nicely apart from this one rest call that requires another request for the design to be complete. Essentially I want to be able to iterate / loop through the first request and dynamically change update the second request.

And my second question is performance, overall the rest calls are taking a bit longer to load - is there something I can do to optimize?

Context:
The first result data gives me an id, slug and title to all the posts I want to display only on the homepage as featured - through that id or slug I want to pass it to the second request - so I can pull in more information about those posts - like featured image and other meta field data.

```
<pre>export default {
  name: 'work',
  data () {
    return {
      loading: false,
      page: null,
      pagesingle: null,
      error: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      this.$http.get('/cms/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?slug=work&_embed')
        .then(result => { 
           this.page = result.data   
           this.$http.get('/cms/wp-json/wp/v2/cases-studes/?slug=case-study-name').then(
               result => this.pagesingle = result.data
             );
         })
    }
  }
}</pre>
```

Comment: What about the second request depends on the first request?

Comment: Hey Roy,
Thank you for you're response - I want the second request to use params from the first request.

('/cms/wp-json/wp/v2/cases-studes/?slug={{dynamic-case-study-name-based-on-the-first-request-iteration}}

Comment: What comes from the first request that you can iterate over?
If you make multiple calls and assign all their results to `this.pagesingle`, they're just going to write over each other. What do you want to do with the multiple results? Please edit your question to make your problem clearer.

Comment: Just updated my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). It will take an array of promises, wait for them all to complete, and then resolve with an array of results.

You would build your array of promises based on the array of slugs and ids in your first request. Maybe something like

```
const promises = result.data.articles.map((article) =>
    this.$http.get(`/cms/wp-json/wp/v2/cases-studies/?slug=${encodeURIComponent(article.slug)}`)
);
```

Getting the results is as easy as

```
Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
    this.arrayOfSinglePages = results.map((result) => result.data);
});
```

Now your `this.page` has the array of `id` (and stuff) and `this.arrayOfSinglePages` has the page details for each of them in the same order.

Comment: Roy I have a similar question to this one...would you please be able to take a quick peek at it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195367/vue-js-fire-a-method-based-on-another-methods-output-unique-id