# Vue JS fire a method based on another method's output unique ID

Tags: api, methods, vue.js

I'm trying to render a list of notes and in that list I would like to include the note's user name based on the user_id stored in the note's table. I have something like this, but at the moment it is logging an error stating ***Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined***, which I get why.

My question is, in Vue how can something like this be executed?

Template:

```
<div v-for="note in notes">
   <h2>{{note.title}}</h2>
   <em>{{user.name}}</em>
</div>
```

Scripts:

```
methods:{
   fetchNotes(id){
      return this.$http.get('http://api/notes/' + id )
      .then(function(response){
         this.notes = response.body;
      });
   },
   fetchUser(id){
      return this.$http.get('http://api/user/' + id )
      .then(function(response){
         this.user = response.body;
      });
   }
},
created: function(){
   this.fetchNotes(this.$route.params.id)
   .then( () => {
      this.fetchUser(this.note.user_id);
   });
}
```

---

***UPDATE:***

I modified my code to look like the below example, and I'm getting better results, but not 100% yet. With this code, it works the first time it renders the view, if I navigate outside this component and then back in, it then fails...same thing if I refresh the page.

The error I am getting is: *[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_name' of undefined"*

Notice the console.log... it the returns the object as expected every time, but as I mentioned if refresh the page or navigate past and then back to this component, I get the error plus the correct log.

Template:

```
<div v-for="note in notes">
   <h2>{{note.title}}</h2>
   <em>{{note.user.user_name}}</em>
</div>
```

Scripts:

```
methods:{
   fetchNotes(id){
      return this.$http.get('http://api/notes/' + id )
      .then(function(response){
         this.notes = response.body;

          for( let i = 0; i < response.body.length; i++ ) {
             let uId = response.body[i].user_id,
                 uNote = this.notes[i];
              this.$http.get('http://api/users/' + uId)
              .then(function(response){
                 uNote.user = response.body;
                 console.log(uNote);
              });
          }

      });
   },
}
```

Comment: `this` is not bound in your `.then` callback. Can you use an arrow function instead of a `function` function?

Comment: @RoyJ which callback? both? I tried changing both callbacks to arrow functions and still behaves the same, the moment I refresh the page it breaks and I get the error message, BUT the console.log shows the correct data.

Comment: Your innermost callback doesn't use `this`, so it doesn't matter. The first callback uses `this`, and it's unbound, so it will not set `notes` properly. Does navigating away clear out `this.notes`? Does navigating back call the `created` hook?

Comment: Made the changes and still no dice. Navigating or refreshing does fire off the created hook and logs the `this.notes` as it should. Another interesting thing I noticed is, when it breaks if I change in the template `{{ note.user.user_name }}` to `{{ note.user.user_email }}` it refreshes the page and displays correctly, but as soon as I navigate away and come back same issue. If I then change it back to `{{ note.user.user_name }}` all is well again.

Comment: Also if I comment out the for loop and any reference to user in template ie: `{{ note.user.user_name }}` it all works like a charm.

Comment: My best guess is that your inner `get` is getting a response without a `body` at some point. I would need to know more about the data at each step to figure it out. Here's a fiddle you can play with. Note the difference if you change the arrow function in `fetchNotes` to a regular one. https://jsfiddle.net/krgbh7ry/

Comment: Yeah I see what you are talking about, but for me the arrow function did not resolve the issue... uugghh. Can you think of another way to accomplish this `fetch notes -> store individual note.user_id -> fetch user with stored user_id` There will be multiple notes so there would need to be some sort of iteration on notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tony, 
Thank you for all your help and effort dude! Ultimately, with the help from someone in the Vue forum, this worked for me. In addition I wanted to learn how to add additional http requests besides the just the user in the fetchNotes method - in this example also the image request. And this works for me.

Template:

```
<div v-if="notes.length > 0">
   <div v-if="loaded === true">
    <div v-for="note in notes">
        <h2>{{note.title}}</h2>
        <em>{{note.user.user_name}}</em>
        <img :src="note.image.url" />
      </div>
    </div>
   <div v-else>Something....</div>
</div>
<div v-else>Something....</div>
```

Script:

```
name: 'invoices',
data () {
   return {
      invoices: [],
      loaded: false,
   }
},
methods: {
fetchNotes: async function (id){
    try{
        let notes = (await this.$http.get('http://api/notes/' + id )).body
        for (let i = 0; notes.length; i++) {
            notes[i].user = (await this.$http.get('http://api/user/' + notes[i].user_id)).body
            notes[i].image = (await this.$http.get('http://api/image/' + notes[i].image_id)).body
        }
        this.notes = this.notes.concat(notes)
    }catch (error) {

    }finally{
       this.loaded = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to show the username of each note's associated user, while the username comes from a different data source/endpoint than that of the notes.

One way to do that:

1. Fetch the notes
2. Fetch the user info based on each note's user ID
3. Join the two datasets into the `notes` array that your view is iterating, exposing a `user` property on each `note` object in the array.

Example code:

```
let _notes;
this.fetchNotes()
    .then(notes => this.fetchUsers(notes))
    .then(notes => _notes = notes)
    .then(users => this.joinUserNotes(users, _notes))
    .then(result => this.notes = result);
```

Your view template would look like this:

```
<div v-for="note in notes">
  <h2>{{note.title}}</h2>
  <em>{{note.user.name}}</em>
</div>
```

[demo w/`axios`](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/NwdGoN?editors=1010)

---

**UPDATE** Based on the code you shared with me, it looks like my original demo code (which uses `axios`) might've misled you into a bug. The `axios` library returns the HTTP response in a `data` field, but the `vue-resource` library you use returns the HTTP response in a `body` field. Attempting to copy my demo code without updating to use the correct field would cause the `null` errors you were seeing.

When I commented that `axios` made no difference here, I was referring to the logic shown in the example code above, which would apply to either library, given the field names are abstracted in the `fetchNotes()` and `fetchUsers()`.

Here's the updated demo: [demo w/`vue-resource`](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/POWVvB?editors=1010).

Specifically, you should update your code as indicated in this snippet:

```
fetchInvoices(id) {
  return this.$http.get('http://localhost/php-api/public/api/invoices/' + id)
    // .then(invoices => invoices.data);  // DON'T DO THIS!
    .then(invoices => invoices.body);     // DO THIS: `.data` should be `.body`
},
fetchCustomers(invoices) {
  // ...
  return Promise.all(
      uCustIds.map(id => this.$http.get('http://localhost/php-api/public/api/customers/' + id))
  )
  // .then(customers => customers.map(customer => customer.data));  // DON'T DO THIS!
  .then(customers => customers.map(customer => customer.body));     // DO THIS: `.data` should be `.body`
},
```

Comment: I tried implementing your solution and I am getting a: notes.map is not a function error message in the const userIds. Any idea as to why? Also I am using Vue Resource instead of Axios...just in case this makes any difference beyond the actual http request.

Comment: Tony, I have updated my initial answer, would you take a quick peek at the updates and let me know what you think.

Comment: `axios` doesn't make a difference here. In your new implementation, you're assigning `notes` *before* you've fully resolved the user information, so your template bindings will error out as `.user` would be `undefined` for each note. You should cache the intermediate note data in a temporary variable (not in `notes`), resolve the user data, then join the two datasets on the user ID. Only then should the **final** result of the joined data be assigned to `notes`.

Comment: Do you mean this line ` this.notes = response.body;? As for an outside variable, do you mean like  an empty array inside the `data() { return { temp: [] } }`?

Comment: Yes, I do mean that line. And by "temporary variable", I mean a local one (declared in `fetchNotes()` in your code). See the codepen demo in the answer for an example. :)

Comment: Tony, I just went in and scrapped everything I had and re-added your solution, and I'm still getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null` error on the const `const userIds = new Set(notes.map(note => note.userId));` in the fetchUsers method.

Comment: That error indicates `notes` is `null`. I would need more context to help troubleshoot that. Do you have a demo (codepen, jsfiddle, github repo, etc.) to reproduce this?

Comment: I can give you access to the bitbucket repo if you don't mind that...do you have an account with bitbucket?

Comment: Yes, username is `tony19`

Comment: I've added the dir of the file in question in the readme file.

Comment: @Sergio I believe I found the problem in your code (you're mapping the incorrect field). See updated answer.

Comment: this was actually something I tried before - changing data to body - it didn't change the error message `Cannot read property 'map' of null`. I tried just now again and same thing error message. Btw, thank you for your help.

Comment: The problem then must be in your API requests/responses. I recommend stepping through the requests in DevTools.

Comment: I think the issue maybe be inside the `populateNotes()` method when it's returning `return this.fetchNotes()`. Shouldn't there be a param with a user id in the  `return this.fetchNotes()`? How else would the API determine which user to pull the associated notes? Also I checked the requests and this is what I got -` Request URL:http://localhost/apiurl/undefined`

Comment: Tony, if I hard code an id in the `return this.fetchNotes(2)` in the `populatNotes` method I get the responses in the dev tools, but nothin on the page. Also I get a new error message `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined` which I think is referring to the `find` in the joinUserNotes method. I don't think the issue is in the api, since I can get Users and Notes independently with no issues at all - which I am doing in other parts of the Vue app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158747/discussion-between-tony19-and-sergio).